# Tensorflow rnn tutorial: ptb_word_lm.py do not generate metadata.tsv for Tensorboard

Tags: csv, metadata, tensorboard, embedding, recurrent-neural-network

I have been working with the PTB language model from the offical tensorflow tutorial.
The files I am using are the files form:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb

I haven't modified any line of code.

When I run you code with the command "python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=simple-examples/data/ --save_path=results/ --model=medium", eveything works perfecty.
My issue is that when I visualize the results in tensorboard with the command "tensorboard --logdir=results/", I only see the words IDs (numbers) and I would like to see the vocabulary (words).

See my screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7cLA.jpg)

Do somebody knows if the code usually generates a metadata.tsv file? When not, how should I proceed to make the code geneate the above mentionned metadata?

I've been trying to find a solution to this issue for the last two days an I would be more than gratefull if you could help me out.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Kind regards

Alex